# first login to enter website with username and passwort

Tags: apache, perl, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have to trying always for Perl, .htaccess and httppd.conf with different Username and Password from LDAP Search. But it  it out of all recognition for username and password. Maybe I am wrong for programmer or what?

**Perl:**

Package:

```
use Net::LDAP;
use Net::LDAP::Extension::SetPassword;
```

Function:

```
my $ldapserver="ldap.server.com";
my $dn="CN=Company IT,OU=Standard Users,OU=Users,OU=Company IT AG,OU=Prod,DC=server,DC=server,DC=com";


my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new( $ldapserver, debug =>0 ) or die $@;
my $result = $ldap->bind( $dn, password => password );

#$result->SetPassword('user');

$result = $ldap->search(
base => "OU=Standard Users,OU=Users,OU=Company IT AG,OU=Prod,DC=server,DC=server,DC=com",
filter => "(mailNickname="*")"
```

**httpd:**

```
<Directory "/opt/csw/apache2/share/cgi-bin">
    SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH "/opt/csw/apache2/lib:/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/instantclient_11g"
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
    AllowOverride Options
    Options +ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthName "Enter Your Network Username/Password"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthBasicAuthoritative off
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.server.com
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Company IT,OU=Standard Users,OU=Users,OU=Company IT AG,OU=Prod,DC=server,DC=server,DC=com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword password
    AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute mailNickname
    require valid-user
</Directory>
```

**htaccess:**

```
AuthName "Enter Your Network Username/Password"
AuthType Basic
Options +ExecCGI
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthBasicAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.server.com
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Company IT,OU=Standard Users,OU=Users,OU=compant IT AG,OU=Prod,DC=server,DC=server,DC=com"
AuthLDAPBindPassword password
AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute mailNickname
require valid-user
```

Comment: AuthLDAPBindDN must be the user to consult the ldap, AuthLDAPURL must be not only the ldap server but the entire LDAP patch Active Directory. Like "AuthLDAPBindDN "userldap@domain"" and "AuthLDAPURL  "ldap://ldap.server.com/OU=Standard Users,OU=Users,OU=compant IT AG,OU=Prod,DC=server,DC=server,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)""

Comment: @JoaoVitorino Thank you very much! It will be work!

Comment: Please mark the question has solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AuthLDAPBindDN must be the user to consult the ldap, AuthLDAPURL must be not only the ldap server but the entire LDAP patch Active Directory. Like

```
AuthLDAPBindDN "userldap@domain"
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.server.com/OU=Standard Users,OU=Users,OU=compant IT AG,OU=Prod,DC=server,DC=server,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
```